# MySQL Docker Container Works on Another PC, but Gives "Access Denied" on Mine

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm facing a perplexing issue with my MySQL Docker container. On another PC with the exact same Docker setup, everything works perfectly. However, on my local Mac machine, while I can connect to the MySQL instance from inside the Docker container without any hitches, I'm repeatedly getting an "Access Denied" error when attempting to connect from the host.

Here's what I've checked and observed:

- **Setup:** I am running MySQL inside a Docker container on my Mac.
- **Connection Inside Container:** Connection to MySQL from within the container works flawlessly.
- **Comparison with Other PCs:** The exact same Docker configuration and setup work seamlessly on another PC. The issue seems unique to my machine.
- **Telnet Test:** I've verified the connection using telnet, and it's successful, meaning the port is open and reachable.
  [image]

Here is my yaml.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    platform: linux/x86_64
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      TZ: Asia/Seoul
    volumes:
     - ~/docker/mysql/volume:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
~
```

init.sql for mount

```
create user 'test2'@'%' identified by '1234';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'test2'@'%' with grant option;

create user 'test2'@'localhost' identified by '1234';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'test2'@'localhost' with grant option;

flush privileges;
```

Comment: What client are you using to try to connect on the host machine? Please update your question with the full text of the error.